# Windows total received bytes is always zero

Tags: windows, network-programming, wireshark, network-protocols

I have a Realtek Gigabit ethernet adapter connected to my PC's PCI port and my OS is Windows 7 x64. I have a device in my LAN which brodcasts data via UDP every 100 ms (source port: 0, dest. port: 5100) and I can see all incoming data via Wireshark. The problem is I can't receive data via the application I developed and total received bytes is always zero in Windows:

[image: Recevied bytes is always zero although I receive data]

I can't even receive data via NetCat. What's the problem? How it is possible that Wireshark is able to receive UDP packets although Windows says total number of received bytes is zero? I can't ping or respond to ping from other computers that are present in my LAN.

```
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
string ip = "192.168.0.1";
int port = 5100;
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port));

var buffer = new byte[1024];
int numBytesReceived = socket.Receive(buffer);
```

Comment: If this is a programming question you need to post some code. If it isn't, it's off-topic.

Comment: I just bind to 5100 port and wait to get data. I uploaded the code

Comment: No, you bind to 192.168.0.1:5100. Try binding to 0.0.0.0:5100.

Comment: First of all, 0 is an invalid port number.

Second, for your program to receive the packets, both the destination IP address and the destination MAC address of the packet have to match those of the machine. Is that the case?

Comment: First of all, I don't know why but receiving tons of UDP packets doesn't update the total received bytes in Windows 7, maybe Windows doesn't give a damn to UDP packets. Since the broadcast IP was 10.0.255.255, I set my IP to 10.0.0.1 with 255.255.255.0 subnet mask but I was wrong. When I changed my subnet mask to 255.255.0.0, I was able to receive the UDP packets and the problem solved. Thank you everyone.

The bind code works, because I check it via netstat command. The port number can be zero if you doesn't matter about source port based on MSDN.

Comment: I didn't say your bind code didn't work, I said it was wrong. If you were sending to 10.00255.255, binding to 192.168.0.1 will specifically prevent yo up from receiving those broadcasts.

Comment: Aha, got it. Thank you @EJP, for sharing your information.